# Склонение названий книг или фильмов

Tags: склонение, названия

Как правильно склонять названия книг, состоящих из нескольких слов, если перед названием не стоит слово "книга" или "фильм"?
Например:
*Это цитата из **"Понедельник(а) начинается в субботу"**.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не надо здесь склонять.
Но дело не в "нескольких словах", а в том, что название — законченное предложение, с подлежащим и сказуемым. Вы пытаетесь поставить подлежащее в косвенный падеж, что грамматически абсолютно невозможно.

Comment: Но в разговорной речи склонение названий используется часто, например, так: *это цитата из "Понедельника".  *это цитата из "Улитки на склоне"*.  В первом случае затруднение устраняется путём сокращения до одного слова.

Answer (score 3):

Если составное наименование образовано двумя существительными разного грамматического рода, то, хотя в отдельных случаях встречается согласование с одним из них, обычно первым (ср.: «Война и мир» написана Л. Н. Толстым), как правило, выбор формы сказуемого затруднителен.
Сравните такие названия, как «Руслан и Людмила», «Ромео и Джульетта», «Тристан и Изольда» и т. п., для которых не подходит ни одна из форм – *написан, написана, написано, написаны*. В подобных случаях следует включать родовое наименование (роман, поэма, пьеса, опера и т. п.).
То же самое рекомендуется для тех случаев, когда согласование возможно, но при этом могут появиться курьезные сочетания, например: «Двенадцать апостолов» стояли на рейде (фрегат); «Волки и овцы» распроданы.

Comment: Как в том анекдоте: «"Правды" нет, "Советская Россия" продана, остался только "Труд" за три копейки».