# Склонение названий книг (односложных, словосочетаний, предложений)

Tags: склонение

Предположим, у Беляева есть произведения: «Голова», «Голова профессора Доуэля», «Голова профессора Доуэля шутит», «Голова и Людмила».

Правило *«Не склоняется в случае, если название является самостоятельным предложением с подлежащим и сказуемым»* единственно или есть ещё особенности?

Верны ли следующие варианты:

1. *Беляев называл «Голову» автобиографической историей.*
2. *Беляев называл «Голову профессора Доуэля» автобиографической историей.*
3. *Беляев называл «Голова профессора Доуэля шутит» автобиографической историей.*
4. *Беляев называл «Голову и Людмилу» автобиографической историей.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если бы у правила были «ещё особенности», оно бы их выделило как исключения. Однако, запрет склонения не подразумевает механической врезки «самостоятельного предложения с подлежащим и сказуемым» в ту же фразу. Предпоследний вариант этим и грешит: эта фраза требует склонения и должна его получить. Правильно будет так: *Беляев называл повесть «Голова профессора Доуэля шутит» автобиографической историей*».

Comment: «правило» — не как скопированное правило из учебника, а просто переформулированный ответ @behemothus отсюда https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/2224/Склонение-названий-книг-или-фильмов Поэтому оно может и не выделить нужное как исключения. Остальные варианты верны?

Comment: Слов нет, верны.