# Читать "Отцы и дети" или "Отцов и детей"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение, ономастика, названия, приложение

Склоняются ли подобные названия, содержащие существительные во мн. ч., тогда, когда не употреблены в функции приложения? Как правильно: «Я читаю "Отцов и детей" Тургенева» или «Я читаю "Отцы и дети" Тургенева»? **Почему?**

Сравните: «Я читаю роман Л. Н. Толстого "Анн**а** Каренин**а**"» и «Я читаю "Анн**у** Каренин**у**" *(не "Анна Каренина"!)*».

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Склонение названий книг или фильмов](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/2224/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: @shampar там вскользь упомянуты названия, включающие в себя сочетание существительных во мн. ч. Вопрос именно об этом. Также не ясен источник рекомендаций ([см. ответ doom](https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/9678/178412)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без родового слова (в данном случае - роман) приложение в кавычках
склоняется: "Я читаю "Отцов и детей" Тургенева".

Ср.: "В пореформенную эпоху
творчество Т. стало заметно оскудевать: он пишет реже и меньше; за пять
лет, отделяющих **«Отцов и детей»** от нового романа «Дым» **[напис.
1865—1867, напеч. 1867], он напечатал только три маленьких произведения".**

Правило:

При согласовании имен собственных и условных наименований обычно учитывается наличие родового понятия: в гостинице "Москва", в романе "Отцы и дети", в пьесе "Вишневый сад". В таком случае приложение ставится в им. пад. При отсутствии родового понятия такое наименование ставится в нужном падеже по контексту: В "Вишневом саде", **об "Отцах и детях"** Прозвища ставятся в им. пад: у Всеволода Большое Гнездо, с Ричардом Львиное Сердце.

См.: Gramma.ru

Answer (score 3):

По-видимому, нет универсального (не зависящего от названия произведения) способа сократить текст, опустив видовое наименование. Для сохранения благозвучия приходится учитывать особенности названия. Из области условно допустимых (в интересах ухода от формальности) упрощений:

> Читаю [роман] "Отцы и дети" Тургенева. Тургенев в "Отцах и детях"
>   повествует о...
>
> Читаю "Анну Каренину" Толстого. Читаю роман "Анна Каренина" Толстого.

В первом случае ("Отцы и дети") "неодушевлённый" вариант винительного падежа *способен* навести на мысль об опущенном видовом наименовании (слово "роман" находилось бы именно  в этом падеже). Склонение же названия произведения ("одушевлённый" вариант падежа) здесь воспринималось бы неестественно ("отцы" или "дети" как предмет "прочтения", да и не авторы ли?), это проявляется и в некоторых других падежах, например: зачитываюсь "Отцами и деть(-я-)ми" Тургенева (?!) - сочетание "детьми Тургенева" звучит излишне просторечно (да и не написали ли они чего?). А вот "Анну Каренину" в "неодушевлённый" винительный падеж уже не поставить: имя указывает на своего обладателя явно сильнее, чем на пропущенное видовое наименование "роман", и сразу возникает ощущение современного рекламного слогана (пейте "Фанта") или ошибки в падеже.

**Вывод:** при оценке допустимости упрощения (за счёт опускания видового наименования произведения) и при выборе варианта падежа (в "допустимых" к упрощению случаях) нужно исходить из того, *как конкретное название произведения взаимодействует с остальным текстом*. В неясных случаях лучше оставить на месте слово "роман".