Склонение названий, содержащих сочетание во мн. числе
Допустим, есть проект "Наши люди".
Можно ли склонять названия проектов без родового слова, если название содержит словосочетание во множественном числе?
Например: Организатором "Наших людей" является местная власть.

См. ответы на форуме, мне они нравятся, все по делу:    https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/433992/Читать-Отцы-и-дети-или-Отцов-и-детей/433994#433994  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/2224/Склонение-названий-книг-или-фильмов   https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/433992/Читать-Отцы-и-дети-или-Отцов-и-детей/433994#433994

Лучше так не писать — звучит двусмысленно, просто с намеком. Если только это не было задумано автором текста.
Так что вспомним Розенталя и запишем так:
Организатором проекта "Наши люди" является местная власть. Тогда все нейтрально.
См. ответы на форуме. Мне они нравятся, все по делу.  Как раз о тех случаях, где нежелательно согласование. Это тоже важно учитывать.
Читать "Отцы и дети" или "Отцов и детей"?
Склонение названий книг или фильмов
Склонение названий произведений
ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ (о курьезных сочетаниях).  Розенталь: §188, пункт 6
 3)если составное наименование образовано 
 двумя существительными разного грамматического 
 рода, то, хотя в отдельных случаях встречается 
 согласование с одним из них, обычно первым (ср.: 
 «Война и мир» написана Л.Н. Толстым). Однако, как 
 правило, выбор формы сказуемого затруднителен; ср. 
 такие названия, как «Руслан и Людмила», «Ромео и 
 Джульетта», «Тристан и Изольда» и т.п., для которых 
 не подходит ни одна из форм – написан, написана, 
 написано, написаны. В подобных случаях следует 
 включать родовое наименование (роман, поэма, пьеса, 
 опера и т.п.). 

 То же самое рекомендуется для тех случаев, когда 
 согласование возможно, но при этом могут появиться 
 курьезные сочетания, например: «Двенадцать 
 апостолов» стояли на рейде (фрегат), «Волки и овцы» 
 распроданы (о билетах на спектакль).


Спасибо вам боьшое за все ответы и ссылки! А если без родового слова, но с глаголом-сказуемым, как согласовать? "Наши люди" стартовал/стартовали?

Здесь  только стартовали, иначе явная грамматическая несочетаемость. А возможность употребления без родового слова  надо смотреть  по контексту.  Частый повтор ни к чему.

Из ответов "Грамоты":

Название в кавычках может склоняться, если употребляется без родового слова: устав "Городского банка" (ОАО). Если родовое слово есть, название в кавычках не склоняется: правление АКБ "Ромашкабанк".

То же самое касается и названий проектов, выставок, книг, фильмов...
✦ Так что можно склонять (на слух, правда, воспринимается двояко, да и по смыслу тоже):
Организатором "Наших людей" является местная власть.
Пример из Нацкорпуса:
Первые рабу-хотэру возникли как подражание Западу, и их хозяева прилагали огромные усилия, чтобы оформить свои отели в стиле, который они почерпнули из просмотра «Римских каникул» или «Унесённых ветром» (Ксения Головина, Елена Кожурина. Япония: нестандартный путеводитель).
• Но почему же "Грамота" так аккуратно говорит (может склоняться)?
Потому что есть названия, которые склонять невозможно или в некоторых контекстах нежелательно (например, "А поутру они проснулись...").
Во избежание курьезов ("Грачи прилетели" вернулись обратно; "Семнадцать мгновений весны" длятся почти 14 часов) или неоднозначности необходимо использовать родовое слово.
Интересное мнение есть вот в этом ответе на нашем форуме: Склонение названий произведений.

@ЛюдмилаПетрикова Добрый вечер, Людмила! Скажите, пожалуйста, а вы внимательно читали мой ответ? "Прошлись" по рекомендованной ссылке?

Добрый день, Римма Михайловна! Признаться, ссылку на ответы Грамоты не заметила. Остальное прочла (и прошла по ссылке). Очень много информации, трудно сразу всё осмыслить, и сайт, как по мне, неудобный: много мелочей, которые отвлекают от сути. Спасибо вам за ваши ответы, я их очень ценю!

Название и склоняется без родового слова. А если родовое слово есть, то склоняется уже оно, а не название. В вашем примере надо склонять название.
Например:
Без родового слова: Посмотрел "Чужого".
С родовым словом: Посмотрел фильм "Чужой".
